# listview view nothing when use android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice

Tags: android

I need your help with listview in android. I use the code below:

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
     People.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
     startManagingCursor(c);

     String[] columns = new String[] {People.NAME};
     int[] names = new int[] {R.id.row_entry};

     mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, c, columns, names);

     lView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

bec i want to have checkbox with it. and after that how can i get all value that check as well.

Thank you,
Raksa,

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your R.id.row_entry to android.R.id.text1